# Implications of running KDE application in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde

I run Ubuntu 9.04 with the Gnome environment by default. Recently I've started playing around with Kdenlive, a KDE application. I've noticed a number of graphical glitches in it and am wondering how many of those glitches may be due to running a KDE app in a Gnome environment.

Are there any implications to running a KDE app in a Gnome environment, or vice-versa? I'm interested in reliability in particular, but also things like any significant performance concerns or what-have-you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few disadvantages one is that KDE apps depend on a fair number of packages and thus occupies additional space a little bit of memory.
And second is that you have to tweak the look of KDE applications. To do this try [qgtkstyle](https://launchpad.net/~soc-krg-nw/+archive/ppa). It's a theme called to integrate KDE applications into Gnome.

Answer (score 4):

KDE applications use KDE libraries, which take time to download, and take up space on your hard drive and in memory. They also don't follow the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/). While they will fit with your theme (I believe qgtkstyle, which skfd suggested, is enabled by default in Ubuntu 9.04), they may still look out of place because of different layout and icons. Lastly, they lack the integration into your desktop environment  that many GNOME applications benefit from.